# Date&Time Picker in java

Tags: java, sql, database, swing, date

I am very new to java and I want user to input time and date on which a football match needs to be scheduled. I'm using SWING jForm as the interface. After getting that date I also want to put that in the database. After searching a lot either I couldn't search the right code or I can't understand that. I'm working on a pretty long project and left with no time to watch tutorial. Any help in this regard would be very highly appreciated.

Or just tell me if I have "YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:ss:SSS" in a String then how can I convert that to Date format?

```
Date d = (Date)dateString didn't worked.
```

Note I am using drag and drop to create items on jFrame.

Comment: you may use tokenizer   StringTokenizer date= new StringTokenizer(dateString, "/ : ", true);

Comment: A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/#q=java+parse+date) brought up [more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-a-date) [than](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496359/how-to-parse-date-string-to-date) [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336643/date-time-parse-in-java) StackOverflow-Answer regarding this topic, one of it being a more or less exact duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat str =new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
```

like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String str = "Sat Nov 23 20:29:30 JST 2013";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date d =  df.parse(str);  
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

Also check [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

(a) Doing date-time work at the last minute is a bad idea. Date-time can be a surprisingly thorny topic.

(b) See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159889/642706) to a similar question.

My example code there uses the third-party library [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), a popular replacement for the notoriously bad java.util.Date/Calendar classes bundled with Java.

That code is just what you need, though you'll need to:

- Adjust the format to your particular needs
- Adjust the time zones to whatever you are handling

Do most of your date-time work within the Joda-Time framework. At the beginning and end, convert between Joda-Time DateTime objects and java.util.Date objects. Lots of Q&A here on StackOverflow to show you that conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Date.parse(String)`, see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) for more details.